# Git workflow - Reverting a feature branch from release branch

Tags: git, github, workflow, git-merge, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to understand a problem in creating a git-workflow

We're thinking of developing several features at once using feature branches, so lets say we have:

```
- F1 (Feature 1)
- F2 (Feature 2)
- F3 (Feature 3)
```

We have just completed features 1 and 3, and merge them into our development branch for integration testing:

```
-F1---Commit1---Commit2----------------------------------
-F2--------Commit1---------------------------------------
-F3--------------------------Commit1---------------------
-Development-------Merge-F1------------Merge-F2----------
```

The development branch is bleeding edge and gets released as part of a nightly build. When we're happy with this, this branch is merged into a staging branch, that is then used for client review:

```
-F1---Commit1---Commit2---------------------------------------------
-F2--------Commit1--------------------------------------------------
-F3-------------------------Commit1-----Commit2---------------------
-Development-------Merge-F1------------Merge-F2---------------------
-Staging-------------------------------------------Merge-Development
```

The client reviews this release on the test environment, but isn't happy with F1. During this time, F3 is code complete and the client would like to review.

**Q - How using git would we get into a position whereby our staging branch has only F2 and F3 for review, but not F1 that the client has now rejected?**

Comment: +1 We are trying to solve the same problem, the potential for a particular feature to make it all the way to staging and then stopped by a client, while the other features in that same package need to continue to live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very popular workflow is [git-flow](http://nvie.com/git-model/). This is basically a model which is very flexible. That doesn't mean you have to do it exactly as described there, but you can take inspiration from it.

In this case a good sollution would be to create a review specific temporary branch which you use to show to the client.

This branch can either be directly based on develop, or based on staging with the specific features merged in.

After the client has reviewed, you can merge the accepted features in the staging branch, or in a specific release branch, and the temporary review branch can be deleted.

This way, you don't have to rewrite history for long-living branches.

Comment: We were looking at using git revert to remove merges, but if we have several merges this can become a bit tricky. The git-flow is really good and something we're loosely basing our workflow upon.

Comment: The solution we've come up with is to be able to 'scrap' or git reset the development and staging branches back to a state prior to a merge if the requirement ever came up that we needed to remove one or several features, as I can imagine it would become complicated trying to perform multiple reverts

Comment: And using revert for merges doesn't actually undo the merge. This means as far as git concerns, the branch is still merged, and merging the branch again is not easy.

Answer (score 7):

You have basically two choices here:

1. revert the `F1` merge in `Development` and then merge that into `Staging`.
   `F1` will vanish from `Development` and `Staging`.
2. reset `Staging` to the commit before merging `F1` and merge `F2` and `F3` by hand.
   You will end up with `Staging` not being a subset of `Development`.
   `F1` will vanish from `Staging` only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `git revert` command to revert merge commits.

You have to specify the merge commit you want to revert and the parent lineage to keep.

```
Development $ git revert -m 1 <Merge-F1 SHA>
```

**Warning.** Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want. **(See [`git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html))**

**Comment on the warning.** In case you will want to re-introduce F1, you will have to rebase the F1 commits, that way it should be possible to merge them in nevertheless.

Comment: I'm at the "comment on the warning" point where a feature has been merged and reverted and is ready to be merged back in again. Can you give me more detail on how to properly rebase?

Answer (score 1):

We have a very similar flow in our project. The way we work is that we have two environments where we demo our customer:

- Development
- Test

We first deploy from the **development** branch to the **Development** **environment**. The customer tests the features individually in this environment.

Then, we merge to the **staging** branch only the features that the customer was happy with.

Finally, we deploy the final pre-release version to the **Test environment** for final review.

In this case we never have to remove a feature but maybe small fixes.